# Need help finding correct html attributes for scraping code

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I want to scrape prices from a website, but I'm not sure how to properly select the right html node and attribute (or text).

So far, the code (that has worked with small adjustments for other websites) looks like this:
vec_microspot<-vector()

```
i=0
for (j in input_microspot$`Microspot Artikel`) {
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=0.25, max=0.5))
  i<-i+1
  vec_microspot[i] <- try(paste0('https://www.microspot.ch/',j)%>%
                          read_html %>%
                          html_nodes('span') %>%
                          html_attr('price'))  
}
```

the `j` in the code refers to the product Nr. that is then pasted onto the base URL. Example product numbers are 0002708143 and 0001560873. So the links are e.g. https://www.microspot.ch/0002708143 and https://www.microspot.ch/0001560873

Or is it not possible to scrape prices from this website as the html_attr or html_text is different for every product?

Answer (score 0):

You want the innerText of the target node which can be extracted with html_text. You need only a single node which, using the up-to-date syntax, can be returned by html_element (singular). Finally, to match on the right price node you can use the following css selector sequence: `#container-productdetailPrice [id$=price]`

So,

```
read_html() %>% html_element('#container-productdetailPrice [id$=price]') %>% html_text()
```

This looks for a parent element with id `container-productdetailPrice`, then uses a descendant combinator (the " " in the selector list) to look for a child with id ending ($) with `price`

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Thanks for your fast and elaborate answer, it worked!
Thanks also for the link, I will have a read

Comment: You are most welcome

Comment: After testing it out I saw that the code somehow might not work for every product. E.g. for the product in 'https://www.microspot.ch/0002400565', it just shows me "2" as ouput. Do you have any idea what might be the problem? Thanks in advance!